# Finding Performance Spikes on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

Is it somehow possible to measure the CPU and/or IO requirements for all installed Visual Studio Addins / Extensions (VS 2012 / 2013)?

**Concrete Problem:** I have quite a lot of Extensions and Addins for Visual Studio 2013 installed and in general it runs smooth, just sometimes i experience ~5-10 sec spikes where VS just freezes. (Without any Addins or Extensions it doesn't happen).
Any idea how to find the problem?

Comment: I've never had to do this myself so don't know but I'd start by looking at the [VS SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it reproduces often enough, you can just attach a debugger to Visual Studio and break in when something is going bad. Conveniently, Visual Studio is a debugger, so if you launch two instances in and in one go Debug > Attach to process, you can just attach to the other. When you hit the issue, break in (quickly) in the other and look at the main thread (it's labled in the threads window.) Look at the stack to see if there are any obvious offenders...

Answer (score 1):

When VS freezes you can run [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) and then analyze the stack for an offending extension. Alternatively [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has a nice real time threads and stack monitor.