# How do I debug a Visual Studio 2017 that freezes during build?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a relatively fresh installation of VS 2017 (15.2) that often-but-not-always freezes during build. I need to kill it completely to proceed.

It's an ASP.Net MVC/SPA that does the freezing. I have other ASP.Net projects that build just fine on same machine. The problematic project builds just fine on my TC build server (using VS build step).

So -- any suggestions as to what I could try to debug? I'm rather clueless and open to suggestions...

OS: WinServer2016.

BR, Anders

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050044/visual-studio-2013-slow-extension-or-add-in-how-to-find-which-one and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467199/finding-performance-spikes-on-visual-studio